# setOnClickListener not working for inflated layout

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, layout-inflater

Button I made in sublayout is not working.
I want my button_sub to work when I click.
I think there is problem with layer inflater, but I still don't get it

```
final View addedView =inflater.inflate(R.layout.sublayout,null);
```

How can I modify my code?

This is my MainActivity class

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
    button3by3 = findViewById(R.id.button_3by3);
    container=findViewById(R.id.container);

    button3by3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            final View addedView =inflater.inflate(R.layout.sublayout,null);
            container.addView(addedView);
            
        }
    });
}
```

Here is my main activity xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="154dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="138dp">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Toast"
        android:id="@+id/button_sub"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and lastly my sublayout activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sublayout);

    btn_sub=findViewById(R.id.button_sub);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    btn_sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(subAction.this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            textView.setText("HELLLLLOOOO");

        }
    });


}
```

Comment: Where are you starting your "sublayout activity"?

Comment: what do you intent to do?  because a fragment would better suit this implementation.

Comment: since I'm very noob to android and java I have never thought of fragment. thanks I should look up

Answer (score 2):

You may try doing inflating operations inside onCreateView or maybe you're only problem is

using getSystemService directly without using getContext so first creating Context context

and then using getSystemService on this context would be another option.

In the activity you may try;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                  inflater =(LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View addedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sublayout,container,false);
        button3by3 = addedView.findViewById(R.id.button_3by3);

        button3by3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

              
              //related code comes here

            }
        });

        return addedView;

    }
}
```

PS: You may also try these inside a fragment.